# Flask hosting issue

Tags: python, linux, flask, hosting

everyone. Hope everything goes well on your side.
I am hosting my flask app on CentOS server. But I faced into some issues.
I can't express more in detail here.
Could you please share a detailed guide of Flask app hosting on Linux server from scratch?
I will highly appreciate it if you do it for me. Looking forward to hearing from you soon.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code/tutorial for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please see [Ask] to learn how to write effective questions.